# Dystopian novel where the protagonist is a girl with powers who has to stop the president from destroying the world

Tags: story-identification, novel, dystopia

This book was long. **Very long**. I read it on my Kindle and I have forgotten about it. The plot is a bit murky in my head but I will give you the details that I remember

- The story is told from the perspective of **multiple** people.
- The main protagonist is a **girl who has some type of power.**
- The **antagonist is some being that is not human**, but that is **not stated what he is in the book**.
- It is a **dystopic** novel.
- There was a **cult following a man who ruled a town**.

The beginning part is a bit hazy, but I do remember the ending part.

- The **president of the USA** is in a **secret place** where he is regarded as a **god** or some wise guy. The fact that he is a president is **revealed later**.
- The guy is regarded as god because he had the last computer.
- The guy asks the main character to convince him **if the world is worth saving or not. Basically, he had the power to save the world, or end it**.
- The antagonists and the protagonists fight.
- The guy is important because he has the **code to activate a sequence to fire nuclear missiles all over the world, thus destroying it**.
- But the story ends such that the antagonist dies and the ruined world is not destroyed.
- The girl grows up and then is known by everyone.

I guess there also was a **military thing** in the story, I don't know.
But the book was long and the **ending was sometime after the president died, sort of an epilogue**.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark, as per the [tour].

Comment: If you read it on your kindle, and bought the book from Amazon, you can look through your list of bought books on Amazon. But if you bought it somewhere else and sideloaded it to your kindle, you wont see it on Amazon.

Comment: @NJohnny I had prime that moment so I had to borrow the book :l

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is Robert McCammon's *[Swan Song](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11557.Swan_Song)*

[image: Front cover of Swan Song]

> An ancient evil roams the desolate landscape of an America ravaged by nuclear war.
>
> He is the Man with the Scarlet Eye, a malevolent force that feeds on the dark desires of the countless followers he has gathered into his service. His only desire is to find a special child named Swan—and destroy her. But those who would protect the girl are determined to fight for what is left of the world, and their souls.
>
> In a wasteland born of rage, populated by monstrous creatures and marauding armies, the last survivors on earth have been drawn into the final battle between good and evil that will decide the fate of humanity....

The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swan_Song_(McCammon_novel)) mentions more matching details:

> Seven years pass; the clouds do not dissipate, radioactive fallout persists, and many survivors suffer from "Job's Mask", a strange skin disease that obscures the head and face with fleshy tissue. The AoE, now a ferocious army of 4,000 soldiers (and including Alvin), moves across America and ravages settlements. The AoE goes to war against and equally armed and fanatical group, the "American Allegiance"; its leader, the self-proclaimed prophet Brother Timothy, is convinced that God lives on Warwick Mountain in West Virginia. Sister and Paul wander the Midwest and meet a group of orphans led by teenager Robin Oakes. Josh, Swan, and Rusty wander the country as a troupe of itinerant entertainers; Swan is blinded by Job's Mask, but shows miraculous new powers by reviving dead plants. Sister and Paul are guided toward Swan by Sister's visions, and are still pursued by the Man with the Scarlet Eye.

....

> The AoE sets out on a campaign toward Warwick Mountain to meet the mysterious "God", who is revealed to be the former United States President. Within his bunker is the control panel for Talons, a doomsday device capable of completely eradicating the Earth's populace by destroying the polar icecaps and flooding the planet. The President activates Talons and is killed by the Man with the Scarlet Eye. Roland tries to kill Swan, but is attacked by Macklin, and both men kill each other. Swan manages to determine the deactivation password and averts disaster. The group leaves the bunker, locks it, and discards the key. The Sun appears in the sky for the first time in seven years. The AoE falls into disarray, and the Man with the Scarlet Eye loses his authority over it. While Josh returns to Mary's Rest, Swan embarks on a journey across America in an effort to heal the world with her powers.

Found with a search for `novel apocalypse president computer`

Comment: If correct, it is a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/184400/book-with-a-female-main-character-and-a-male-protector-after-a-nuclear-or-chemic?noredirect=1&lq=1